# Send mail with the data of a foreach in wocoomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found a way to save all the information of all the orders that have been made in a table, but in a section of the table there is a link and I need that when that link is pressed, it sends a personalized email.

The truth is that I am new to this and it would help me a lot to know how to do i

```
<?php
$orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );


        foreach( $orders as $order ){
                    
                
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>" . $order->get_id() . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $order->get_billing_first_name() . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $order->get_billing_city() . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $order->get_billing_phone() . "</td>";
                      
                      echo "<td><a class='page-title-action'  >" . Enviar_Correo . "</a></td>";
            
                      echo "</tr>";
            
            
                }
        
?>
```

I need that when I press, it brings me the specific data of the line  and sends an email with that data
[image]

Comment: **Hint:** (1) at least you need to make the button triggering a PHP script sending out the email. (2) make sure you pass a parameter when you make the (1) above, say an ID or something so that the PHP script knows what should be sent out.

Comment: I'm really very new, I understand what you're telling me, but I don't know how to pass it to code